# Change timestamp from 24 hour to 12 hour and append via jQuery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, ajax

I have a table with many timestamps, I have detected the busiest hour using the query

```
    $query = 'SELECT hour(date) AS h FROM bike_main GROUP BY h ORDER BY count(*) DESC LIMIT 1';
    $result = mysql_query($query);
    $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
```

and outputting it with:

```
<h3 id="hour"><?php echo $row['h']; ?></h3>
<p>is the busiest hour</p>
```

This only returns "17", what I would like this to return is 5-6PM. I have tried using:

```
if ($('#hour').val() == '17') {
$(this).val('5 - 6PM');
} else {
    console.log('hour not logged');
}
```

the console logs "hour not logged" every time, and my JS is wrapped within a $(document).ready wrapper.

EDIT: This question has been resolved. Rather than having a very long if/else statement I have tried to use;

```
for (var hour = 1; hour < 13; hour++) {
    var nextHour = hour+1;
    if($('.hour').text() == hour) {
        $(this).val(hour + '-' + nextHour + ' AM');
    }
}
```

but this doesn't seem to work.

Comment: change val() to text() or html().My question is at what point of time does the jquery code execute.

Comment: @Kapilgopinath the code is executed on $(document).ready

Answer (score 1):

Use `.text()` instead of `.val()`

```
if ($('#hour').text() == '17') {
        $('#hour').text('5 - 6PM');
} else {
    console.log('hour not logged');
}
```

Comment: thanks, one question: I have tried outputting this via very long JS if/else statement:
if ($('.hour').text() == '0') {
 $(this).val('12-1 AM');
} else if ($('.hour').text() == '1') {
    $(this).val('1-2 AM');
} else if $('.hour').text() == '2') {
 $(this).val('2-3 AM');
} else if $('.hour').text() == '3') {
 $(this).val('3-4 AM');
} else if $('.hour').text() == '4') {
 $(this).val('4-5 AM');
} else if $('.hour').text() == '5') {
 $(this).val('5-6 AM');
}

for (var i = 0; i < 23; i++) {
 var d = i+1; 
    if($('.hour').text() == 'i' {
     $(this).val('i-d AM');
    })
}
doesn't seem to work.

Comment: sorry about that, didn't realize what Stack Overflow's comment formatting was like. I have updated the main thread.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
 if ($('#hour').text() == '17') {
        $('#hour').text('5 - 6PM');
    } else {
        console.log('hour not logged');
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

you can even get the date/time formatted via PHP using https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.date.php

```
$query = 'SELECT date FROM bike_main GROUP BY h ORDER BY count(*) DESC LIMIT 1';
$result = mysql_query($query);
$row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
```

in html

```
<h3 id="hour"><?php echo date('ga', $row['date']); ?></h3>
<p>is the busiest hour</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
if (document.getElementById('hour').innerHTML == '17') 
{
    document.getElementById('hour').innerHTML = '5 - 6PM';
} 
else {
    console.log('hour not logged');
}
```